# how to make a div stay in the same position and then dissapear at a specific point

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm wondering how you can make a div apear at a certain point of the page and stay in the exact same spot untill you reach a specific point of the page

kinda like they have on http://www.squarespace.com where you see a imac screen which stays on the screen until you reach a specific point

can this be done without using js
either way can someone let me know how?

Comment: Your first paragraph ends mid-sentence *"reach a certain point of the...."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean making a div show up when the user has *scrolled* to a certain point in the page and then disappear when they *scroll* to another point.

This isn't technically possible with CSS. There might be a way to make it look like this with other elements covering it up, but I'll focus on doing it with JS for now.

Essentially, you want to

```
// set up limits for show/hide
var SHOW_Y = 100,
    HIDE_Y = 800;

// function to be called every time
// the page is scrolled
function scrolled() {
  if(window.scrollTop < SHOW_Y) {
    hide(this);  
  } else if(window.scrollTop < HIDE_Y) {
    show(this);
  } else {
    hide(this);
  }
}

// helper function which hides an element
function hide(element) {
  element.style.display = 'none';
}

// helper function which shows an element
function show(element) {
  element.style.display = 'block';
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('your-element');
  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrolled.bind(element));
});
```

I would probably do this using CSS classes rather than `display` properties, in order to control the way that the element disappears and reappears, but this should give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a script like [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) or [ScrollMagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/).